# Attaching the source to a library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded this library for low level Java keyboard hooks:

http://ksquared.de/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

It works great, but I want to attach the source to it. The source is included as .java files, but when I go to attach them to the library in eclipse it only wants a jar or zip file. I tried zipping the .java files but it didn't work. I've never attached a source before, can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to attach sources by pointing to a folder. I haven't used Eclipse in years, so I do not remember where it is. When you zip source files, you need to zip the root of the namespace directory (`de`, in your case).

Comment: Ahh, I see. I thought only the folder with the files needed to be zipped, not the root. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You don't actually need to zip them, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You can attach the source as either a zip file, a folder in the workspace or an external folder. In your project, right click and select `Build Path -> Configure Build Path` and then in the libraries tab find your library and expand it. There will be a line there about source attachment. On that like, hit the `Edit` button and then select the location of your source files.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It says "An internal error occurred during: "Setting build path"." The zip method works for me.

Comment: You might want to look at the error log (Window -> Show View -> Error log) so see what caused that error.