# No source attachment in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javadoc

I am trying to use an external `.jar` file in my project. I have put that `.jar` file in my project's /lib folder, and I have referenced it in the build path. However, when I try to use it in code, I can't get the javadoc for it, nor I can see the actual code from the referenced classes. It says it **has no source attachment**. What is it meant by source attachment? I do have a javadoc folder that came with it, but when I attach it to my build path, it still reports it could not found the javadoc for the classes. Any ideas on that?

I want to be able to see the javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .jar file is the generated packed classes of the java code. Some jars will come with java doc and code and others won't.

**For recent Eclipse versions:**

right-click the jar in question (in the referenced jars, not the physical jar) and choose Preferences -> Javadoc. Here give a correct location (zip/URL) to the correct javadoc. (Select Validate!)

**For older Eclipse versions:**

First: Navigate to the jar itself in the Eclipse project explorer (to the left) and try to open aclass of the jar. Then, you will see the warning that *it has no source attachment*, and a button to attach the source code.

Then, push the button, select "external folder" and then navigate to the folder with source you already have.

Answer (score 1):

hope I got you right:

try to right-click the jar in the references jar tab and go to Preferences -> Javadoc.

choose the right location to the correct javadoc and press "Validate" afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Jar files can be built with or without source code.  It's normal for 3rd party applications to produce a binary jar and a source jar, but it isn't required.  The message is telling you that it doesn't know where the source code is for the library you are using.  It's been a long time since I've done this in eclipse, but there is a way in the project settings to point each library jar to the corresponding source location (which can be a jar, zip file or directory).

Here are a couple of references

- [Attach the Source in Eclipse of a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180411/attach-the-source-in-eclipse-of-a-jar)
- [Attaching the source to a library in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955608/attaching-the-source-to-a-library-in-eclipse)